# Facebook Login localhost

Tags: php, facebook, autenticação, oauth, virtualhost

[Ajax Facebook Connect with jQuery & PHP](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-facebook-connect-with-jquery-php)

Não consigo rodar o facebook na maquina local. Quero implementar o Login com Facebook no meu site mais gostaria de testar localmente acima esta o login que estou a tentar implementar!

Comment: É, precisa de uma máquina BEM potente pra rodar o facebook na máquina local... Brincadeiras à parte, qual o problema que você está tendo?

Comment: O problema é que quero testar o "Login com Facebook" na maquina local(Localhost) e depois implementar no meu site que ainda não esta alojado

Comment: O problema é você querer testar? :)

Comment: Não, mais como introduzir no meu site que esta no servidor local

Comment: Seu servidor local roda PHP?

Comment: Sim, funciona muito bem!

Comment: Teste o código abaixo nele então, que deve funcionar normalmente. Se der algum erro, aí vc avisa.

Answer (score 1):

Eis um exemplo bem simplificado de como usar a API do facebook pra PHP, que se encontra **[aqui](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)**:

```
<?php
   require '../src/facebook.php';
   $facebook = new Facebook( array(
      'appId'  => 'PONHA SEU APPID AQUI',
      'secret' => 'PONHA SEU TOKEN AQUI',
   ));

   $user = $facebook->getUser();
   if ($user) {
      try {
         $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $fberror) {
         error_log($fberror);
         $user = null;
      }

      $link = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
   } else {
      $link = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
   }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
<?php if ($user) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Login com Facebook</a>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($user) {  ?>
      <h3>Voce:</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
      <h3>Perfil:</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
<?php } else {?>
      <h3>Erro:</h3>
      <?php echo $fberror; ?>
<?php } ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Teste na sua máquina com seu ID e seu TOKEN, e informe se está tendo algum erro.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,
você vai precisar criar um alias para o seu projeto. Hoje você está acessando assim localhost/seuprojeto. Desta forma o Facebook não consegue entender, você vai precisar criar uma alias para o seu projeto, deixando o acesso para ele assim local.seuprojeto.com.br. Para fazer isso, dê uma olhada nesse post: http://www.raphaelfiga.com/desenvolvimento/instalando-configurando-virtualhost-apache-windows/

Espero ter ajudado.